# char type and re-encoding ASCII text into UTF-16

Tags: c++, c, string, encoding, utf-8

I am using `libiconv` to convert my char array into a UTF-16 string. I have doubts.

1. signature of `iconv` function

   ```
   size_t iconv(iconv_t cd,
                const char* * inbuf, size_t *inbytesleft,
                char* * outbuf, size_t *outbytesleft);
   ```

   that means, `char` is used to hold whatever type of characters being converted to (char vs wide char).
   My C teacher at school teaches me that for odd or unreadable characters, we should use wchar_t. I'm so much confused now.
2. I tested this method on an `input = "KOTEX"` as `ASCII` encoded type and wish to output another string of double length encoded as `UTF-16`. It fails immediately. But if I change the destined code page into `UTF-8`, it'll work but the data returned is lost. Why is that ?

Comment: See if this helps https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/iconv-Examples.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The buffer arguments to `iconv` are, in effect, `char *` but that is not intended to imply that they actually represent C strings. (It might have been less confusing had the interface used `uint8_t*` instead, but that's anachronic; `iconv` was around before `stdint.h`)

The Posix standard (and the Linux manpage) try to make this clear:

> The type of `inbuf` and `outbuf`, `char **`, does not imply that the objects pointed to are interpreted as null-terminated C strings or arrays of characters. Any interpretation of a byte sequence that represents a character in a given character set encoding scheme is done internally within the codeset converters. ([Posix.2008](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/iconv.html#tag_16_232_07)

So if you are planning on converting to UTF-16, you should provide an output buffer with an appropriate datatype for UTF-16. `wchar_t` is *not* an appropriate datatype; on many systems, it will be too big. `uint16_t` would be fine.

Note that there are actually three different UTF-16 encodings (the names are system-dependent; the ones here are recognized by Gnu `iconv`):

- `UTF16LE` (or `UTF-16LE`): "Little endian" UTF-16. In this format, the low-order byte of each character is first, followed by the high-order byte. `KOTEX` is

  ```
  {0x4B, 0x00, 0x4F, 0x00, 0x54, 0x00, 0x45, 0x00, 0x58, 0x00}
  ```
- `UTF16BE` (or `UTF-16BE`): "Big endian" UTF-16. In this format, the high-order byte of each character is first, followed by the low-order byte. `KOTEX` is:

  ```
  {0x00, 0x4B, 0x00, 0x4F, 0x00, 0x54, 0x00, 0x45, 0x00, 0x58}
  ```
- `UTF16` (or `UTF-16`): either `UTF16BE` or `UTF16LE`, depending on whether the machine is big-endian or little-endian; converted strings start with a [Byte Order Mark (BOM)](http://unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#BOM). On a little-endian machine (mine), `KOTEX` is

  ```
  {0xFF, 0xFE, 0x4B, 0x00, 0x4F, 0x00, 0x54, 0x00, 0x45, 0x00, 0x58, 0x00}
  ```

  On a big-endian machine, it would be:

  ```
  {0xFE, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x4B, 0x00, 0x4F, 0x00, 0x54, 0x00, 0x45, 0x00, 0x58}
  ```

The fact that `UTF16` (unadorned with endian specification) always starts with a BOM means that you have to remember to provide an extra (2-byte) character in the output buffer. Otherwise, you'll end up with `E2BIG`.

In all three of these encodings, characters outside of the [basic multilingual plane (BMP)](http://unicode.org/roadmaps/bmp/) require two (two-byte) character positions, a so-called [surrogate pair](http://unicode.org/glossary/#surrogate_pair). All ascii characters are on the BMP, so you don't need to worry about this for ascii-to-utf16 conversion, but you would if you were doing utf8-to-utf16.